# AngularJS not loading in IE9 Quirks mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I have a simple Angular app which is loaded into a third party frameset - yes a frameset.
The app loads fine in Chrome and IE8 but doesn't at all in IE9.
When testing outside the frameset in IE9, it loads fine. As such I think the issue is that the frameset triggers IE9 quirks mode, and Angular just doesn't want to load in quirks mode.
I can't force standards mode because I only have control of the code within the frame.

Essentially my question is - is it possible to get Angular (v1.2.26) working in IE9 quirks mode or is it a lost cause?
I've tried everything from the Angular IE guide, and also disabled sce.

```
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
```

Below is the index.html that is loaded within the frameset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"
    xmlns:ui="http://angular-ui.github.io"
    xmlns:az="xxxx"
    id="ng-app"
    ng-app="xxxx">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>xxxx</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-b543e73e.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main/main-a902793d.css">
    <script src="scripts/vendor-55f700d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ui:view id="view-app"></ui:view>
    <script src="scripts/main-bb00ee53.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the framed document?

Comment: Yes, my code (as now shown above) has a doctype but the third-party framing code (which unfortunately I don't have access to) doesn't. As such I think there's no way to get into standards mode. I just wonder if Angular can work in quirks mode at all.

Comment: Some versions of Angular will support IE 8, but no version of Angular will support Quirks Mode.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell Angular simply doesn't work in Quirks mode.